# Mandate a group inside regex OR group

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, text-extraction

I want to match alphanumeric characters and it must contain digits compulsorily.
Basically, I want to extract an order number which is a combination of alphabets, digits and a few special characters. I  wrote the following regex

```
String invoiceRegex = "(?<=((?i)(PO|P/O|ORDER)([\\s|.]{0,4})(number|no)?[|: -.]{0,10}))([\\dA-Z:-]*)";
```

But then it matches the invalid information such as IMMEDIATELY and other words. So I want a regex that matches alphanumeric characters with digits mandatory.

ex:  From text "P/O No. : P9:8774" i want P9:8774.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.I made a group with alphabets an option and digit mandatory.and then repeated this group with +.

now it looks something like this. an

```
String invoiceRegex = "(?<=((?i)(PO|P/O|ORDER)([\\s|.]{0,4})(number|no)?[|: -.]{0,10}))([A-Z:-]*\\d+)+";
```